# bottom up rails app associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I'm building a rails app from the bottom up and need a little guidance on the model associations.

We have clients and engage them on multiple projects.
The client has users (their employees) who work on projects and make contributions to the project with files and notes.
We also collaborate with our clients on projects (add files, notes).
Projects have contributors (users or sub contractors that may be part of another client) who make contributions (files, notes).

So model wise I want to ensure I'm capturing everything properly.  Here's what I have, but I'm not confident its all right and am open to other associations.

```
Client
 has_many :projects
 has_many :users

Project
 belongs_to :client
 has_and_belongs_to_many :contributors
 has_and_belongs_to_many :contributions

User
 belongs_to :client
 belongs_to :contributor
 has_many :contributions

Contributor
 has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
 has_one :user
 has_many :contributions

Contribution
 has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
 belongs_to :contributor
```

I think contributions will be associated with models for files and notes; projects may be associated with a "next steps" model...  All as nested resources I think.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of splitting user and contributor model? Why can't it be one model?

Comment: sometimes users from one client may contribute to a project of another client, or users may not access a project... Thought was to store contributors on a project basis.  Not the user but a reference of users (maybe join table).  unnecessary?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed [the guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)? Did you do any sort of paper prototype of the model domain to clarify all these associations? Those are important parts of the process that for any moderately complex problem domain will be important for getting things off on the right foot.

I would probably make the `:contributor` association on `Contribution` a `has_one` association rather than `belongs_to` but that's probably just preference. I also agree with [Phobos98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091860/bottom-up-rails-app-associations#comment19490825_14091860) that `Contributor` is an unnecessary distinction from `User`. I think `Contribution` is a very nicely conceived model for relating user actions to projects. Most authentication frameworks like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) allow you to specify roles and something like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) would allow you fine-grained control over the permissions.

As far as nested resources go, that's really something different that just relates to how your app makes its data available. It's like building a house. You put up the walls and there's people and belongings inside, but the number of windows (routes) controls who can see what. Yes, it's helpful to have these routes available but they're not required at the beginning in order to make sure the data model is in place.

Did you actually try the model you have here and see if it worked? With scaffolding, you can try things quickly, and Rails makes changing the data model trivial, so there's no reason you can't be a little more agile with this. Just try it out and figure out what works and what doesn't. Then, you'll know what needs to change.

Comment: Thanks for everything here.  I'm traveling with no ROR and am planning this on iPad.  I read all association docs, and association chapters of a learning rails book on the plane.  Ill try it when travels are done. Until then I'm working to have a better understanding of the "ground floor".  Ill draw out the tables, sounds like a good way to plan, been doing it in my head.... Thanks, I've planned on rolling my own authentication to app (give access in) was thinking model interaction would dictate from there.  Thanks!

Comment: Yah, there's rarely any good substitute for actually running code and seeing what works and what doesn't. Using something like OmniGraffle on the iPad is a great way to plan out relationships like this, but pencil and paper is fast and easy to throw away so less fear of making a mistake. :) Good luck.